I need a popup window to come up when a user clicks on a worksheet, but ONLY if a checkbox is checked
I have a few people that need constant reminders of instructions inside their excel sheets. In my template I have a code written so if someone clicks on a tab, a popup window displays a message. This works just fine. What I want to do is have a hidden cell someplace that if I set the value to "1" or "Yes" then I want the popup to happen but if I set the value to "0" or "No", then I don't want the popup to happen. This way when I am setting up the template it will default to the popup but if its someone that doesn't need the reminder, I can go to my hidden cell and change the value so the popup doesn't happen for them. I figure this would be easier to toggle on/off instead of going into Developer for each person.
This is what I have in Developer for "This Workbook". The Sheet Name that I want the popup on is called "WJCR". Again this works fine but I want to have it look at a cell and if the value is set to "1" then run this but if its set to "0" then don't run this.
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)

    On Error Resume Next

    If Sh.Name = "WJCR" Then

        MsgBox "Please ensure to have MACROs Enabled by clicking the link in the Toolbar above the cells. Please Ensure to hit the UPDATE button after you copy/paste into the TS Original tab.", vbInformation, "WJCR Instructions"

    End If

End Sub

Thank you in advance for your expertise!

If Sh.Range("Z1") = 1 Then Msgbox...

Avoid using "On Error Resume Next" unless you are certain that a specific error is being intentionally ignored.

thank you - should i just remove "on error resume next" or do i need to replace it with something?

If Sh.Name = "WJCR" AND Sh.Range("Z1") = 1 Then...

is the obvious answer.
Only note is if you need the hidden cell to not be in sheet WJCR, for example, in a different sheet that is hidden. You´d instead have to use
If Sh.Name = "WJCR" AND Worksheets("HiddenSheetName").Range("A1") Then

